# How to make importing file more dynamic in R

Tags: r

I would like to make importing file more dynamic. So, I want to take location of the file for the day that is written in the folder with the R project.
So, if folder location with R project has a name "AAA_DD.MM.YYYY", take different file with the same date.

So again, if my folder has a date DD.MM.YYYY, export different file with the same DD MM and YYYY.

```
data <- read.table("//aaaa/bbb/ccc/YYYMMDD/YYYYMMDD_file.flt", header=TRUE, sep="|")
```

Thanks in advance for help and sorry if you didn't understand me.
If you have easier way to do this, please post the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below I do the following steps to illustrate what you need to do: I create a directory with my birthday, then go into this directory, find the directory name using some base R commands, remove the points from the directory name and write a random vector to file with this found directory name. Can this help you to get to what you need?

```
dir.create("04.10.1990")
setwd("./04.10.1990")
cur_folder <- basename(getwd())
splitted <- paste(unlist(strsplit(cur_folder, "[.]")),collapse="")
x <- rep("blah", 1000)
write.csv(x, file = paste0(splitted, "_file.csv"))
```